# How to serialize java class to json in clojure

Tags: java, json, serialization, clojure

I have many java classes, which can contain another class

```
public class SomeClass(){
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;
}

public class AnotherClass(){
    private String anotherkey;
    private String anothervalue;
}
```

How can convert SomeClass to json in clojure? Already tried to use [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire#cheshire), [clojure/data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json), but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everybody. Problem was solved by [clj-gson](https://github.com/spoon16/clj-gson)

Answer (score 3):

I have renamed your example classes to make it more concrete:

```
public class Person {
  String  name;
  Address address;
}

public class Address {
  String street;
  String city;
}
```

Here is an outline of what to do. You simply define a conversion function for each class, and then compose them hierarchically:

```
(defn address->clj [address]
  {:street  (.-street address)
    city    (.-city address)})

(defn person->clj [person]
  {:name     (.-name person)
    address  (address->clj (.-address person))})
```

Consider some sample data (NOTE: constructor details omitted)

```
(def addr-1    (Address. "123 Main St" "Anytown"))
(def person-1  (Person.  "Joe Smith" addr-1))

(someClass->clj  person-1)    ; Convert Java person-1 obj
```

You will get a Clojure map back that looks like:

```
{:name      "Joe Smith"
 :address   {:street "123 Main St" 
             :city   "Anytown"}}
```

---

Update

If you are working with a Java bean, please see also:

- the [bean-dip](https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip/) library
- the [clojure.java.data](https://github.com/clojure/java.data) library

Comment: @ykembayev I don't understand people who come here and ask questions, and get detailed answers like this which no doubt took time to compile, and don't even bother to upvote the answer.

Comment: @Josh _Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I understand your question correctly. If you would like to convert java bean to clojure data structure, you could simply use clojure **bean** API. Using postwalk, you could also convert all inner part too. Find an example in bellow

```
  (let [ao (doto (AnotherClass.)
                 (.setAnotherkey "Ano")
                 (.setAnothervalue "Ano-value"))
    o (doto  (SomeClass.)
             (.setKey "A")
             (.setValue "A-value")
             (.setAnotherClass ao))]
   (->> (dissoc (bean o) :class)
         (w/postwalk (fn [v]
                    (if (contains? #{AnotherClass SomeClass} (type v))
                     (dissoc (bean v) :class)
                     v)))))

;;Output {:anotherClass {:anotherkey "Ano", :anothervalue "Ano-value"}, :key "A", :value "A-value"}
```

Comment: thanks, I searched for universal method do it. Problem was solved by clj-gson

Answer (score 1):

With `clojure.data.json` you can extend writer protocol when necessary. E.g.:

```clj
(require 'clojure.data.json)
(extend-type java.util.UUID
  clojure.data.json/JSONWriter
  (-write [object ^PrintWriter out]
     (.print out (str " something "))))
```